# Why is link_to running a method inside it when the view is visited?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, model

I have this link in the **view**:

```
  <%= link_to "Pay in PayPal", @order.paypal_url(edit_order_url, payment_notification_url), class: "btn btn-success" %>
```

And this in the **model**:

```
 class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 def paypal_url(return_url, notify_url)
    # ... Do stuff
    self.update_attribute(:payment_in_process, true)
    # Do more stuff...    
  end
```

---

When I visit the **view**, the model gets its attribute updated. I do not want this. I only want the attribute updated if the link is clicked.

Know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me start with a brief overview of `link_to` method. According to [api](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to), this method creates a link tag of the given `name` using a URL created by the set of `options`:

```
link_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

In your particular case, the `name` is "Pay in PayPal", which is a plain string. The second parameter, `URL`, is a bit more complicated, as you do not pass any kind of an absolute or relative path to content on the website, but call the method on an object instead:

```
@order.paypal_url(edit_order_url, payment_notification_url)
```

What happens here is that particular method `paypal_url` being instantly called, and `link_to` expects this method to return a correct `URL`. The same happens with the familiar examples from documentation, e.g.:

```
link_to "Profile", profile_path(@profile)
# => <a href="/profiles/1">Profile</a>
```

Here `profile_path` is a method which accepts an argument to get its unique `id` and therefore being able to generate a correct path. Same rule applies here: this method gets called as soon as user requests the page with the link.

So the first thing to do is to remove everything related to postprocessing of a click out of `paypal_url` method.

But you want to make those things work after a link is clicked. Actually a decision on whether a user clicked a link (or not) is made in a controller layer. Saying it simply, in case a controller action is called, then you know that a user clicked a link.

So the step two is to make some kind of request to your inner controller action and put the related logics there. In case `paypal_url` leads a user to your inner website page, you probably have that action implemented already. On the other hand, your `paypal_url` might lead to outer page, like actual paypal processing... In that case you could achieve the same with redirection or ajax request.